# How to parse a date to get the string in a particular format

Tags: string, date, groovy

I have the date in the format Mon Nov 01 00:00:00 PDT 2010 I want MM/yyyy format.

```
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.text.ParseException;

 Date str='Mon Nov 01 00:00:00 PDT 2010'

 try {         
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");        
 Date date = sdf.parse("Mon Nov 01 00:00:00 PDT 2010");         
 System.out.println("date: " + date.toString());    
 } 
 catch (ParseException ex) {        
 ex.printStackTrace();    
 }
```

How to get only MM/yyyy format from the string to a variable so that i can use it for displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach for Groovy 2.5+ on Java 8

```
new Date('Mon Nov 01 00:00:00 PDT 2010').toLocalDate().format('MM/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Groovy's `parse` and `format` methods like so:

```
String str = 'Mon Nov 01 00:00:00 PDT 2010'

String monthAndYear = Date.parse('EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy', str).format('MM/yyyy')
```

Comment: Getting an error No signature of method: static java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.Date) values: [EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy, 'Mon Nov 01 00:00:00 PDT 2010']

Comment: You sure you're using groovy? That works, and has for years https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5157904197877760

Comment: @tim_yates.Sorry my bad.I am getting the input as Date object.So parsing the date is throwing an error.I edited my question from String to Date.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Date.format()` (which uses [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))) to convert the date you parsed into a string which contains MM/yyyy